# Whats wrong if we compare 2 roots instead of the datas for the 2 identical binary trees problem?

Tags: java, tree

This is my code for the 2 identical binary trees question:

```
if(root1==null && root2==null){
    return true;
}    
else if(root1==null && root2!=null){
    return false;
}
else if(root1!=null && root2==null){
    return false;
}

return root1.data==root2.data && isIdentical(root1.left,root2.left) && isIdentical(root1.right,root2.right);

}
```

Whats wrong if in the return statement I changed root1.data==root2.data to root1==root2

Comment: What is wrong is that you are testing identity instead of equailty by only comparing the roots.

Answer (score -1):

If you have *two* trees as input then this means `root1!=root2`. When we say they are identical, we don't mean they are the same, single tree, but they are like copies of each other, which means that the nodes are distinct, but the values in those nodes match. So you need to compare the data in the tree, not the node references.

If we would have `root1==root2`, then actually you just have one tree and have two references to it.

Comment: You also are conflating identity with equality. Identity means they are the same tree. Equaliity means they have the same content.

Comment: The OP speaks of *"the 2 identical binary trees question"*. It is obvious that "identical" here does not have the strict sense that you insist on, @MarquisofLorne, otherwise the OP would not have asked the question. In English "identical" does not always have that strict sense. For example: "identical twins".